# how to use Scrapy ajax send request and get json data

Tags: python, scrapy

I am searching answer to scrape table data on https://www.shpgx.com/html/jkLNGdaj.html.

Desired data exists in https://www.shpgx.com/marketzhishu/dataList

formdata:  zhishukind=6&area=22&starttime=&endtime=&start=0&length=25&ts=1589333667544

pagination exists in response:

[image]

Used this code to run, but got 400 ERROR

```
class ShpgxLngSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shpgx_lng'
    allowed_domains = ['www.shpgx.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.shpgx.com/html/jkLNGdaj.html/']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.shpgx.com/marketzhishu/dataList"
        headers = {"Host": "www.shpgx.com",
                    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0",
                    "Accept": "*/*",
                    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.3",
                    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                    "Content-Length": "75",
                    "Origin":" https://www.shpgx.com",
                    "DNT": "1",
                    "Connection": "keep-alive",
                    "Referer": "https://www.shpgx.com/html/jkLNGdaj.html",
                    "Pragma": "no-cache",
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"}
        body='''{"zhishukind": "6",
                    "area": "22",
                    "starttime":"",
                    "endtime":"",
                    "start": "0",
                    "length": "25",
                    "ts": "1589333667544"}'''

        yield FormRequest(url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=body)

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        print(data)
```

```
020-05-12 22:54:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://www.shpgx.com/marketzhishu/dataList> (referer: https://www.shpgx.com/html/jkLNGdaj.html)
2020-05-12 22:54:59 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://www.shpgx.com/marketzhishu/dataList>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this code working:

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = "https://www.shpgx.com/marketzhishu/dataList"
    headers = {"Referer": "https://www.shpgx.com/html/jkLNGdaj.html"}
    formdata = {"zhishukind": "6",
                "area": "22",
                "starttime":"",
                "endtime":"",
                "start": "0",
                "length": "100",
                "ts": "1589333667544"}

    yield FormRequest(url, method='POST', headers=headers, formdata=formdata)

def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    print(data['root'])
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I use `start_urls` to get cookies (after that I can create a POST request). Second, your `body` is not correct (you need to use `formdata` instead). There is no need to use so many `headers` also:

```
import scrapy
import json


class ShpgxLngSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shpgx_lng'
    allowed_domains = ['www.shpgx.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.shpgx.com/html/jkLNGdaj.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        headers = {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "Referer": "https://www.shpgx.com/html/jkLNGdaj.html",
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            url="https://www.shpgx.com/marketzhishu/dataList",
            method="POST",
            headers=headers, 
            formdata={
                "zhishukind": "6",
                "area": "22",
                "starttime":"",
                "endtime":"",
                "start": "0",
                "length": "25",
                "ts": ""
            },
            callback=self.parse_search,
        )

    def parse_search(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        print(data)
```